# Windows Phone 7 (WP7) PhotoChooserTask with Crop

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've seen this in a number of apps but can't find anything in the documentation or online samples.

When you invoke the PhotoChooserTask some apps enable you to resize / crop to use only a portion of that image (by showing a white rectangle). How can I use this and set my own dimensions for the target image?

Comment: Great question, hard to find info on this topic. This is a great way to handle it, manually cropping is hard to get right, and this works extremely well.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the width and height of the desired image and the [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=vs.92%29) will automatically create the crop mechanism.

```
photoChooser.PixelHeight = 500;
photoChooser.PixelWidth = 500;
```

There are some known issues with this method in the pre-nodo emulator; using the 7.1.1 tools I have not had any problems with this method.

Comment: Rolled back question and posted answer as CW.

Comment: I assumed this would be done using some custom control and avoided it (out of laziness) until I saw this. So simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Those apps will be doing the cropping themselves. There is not built in way to crop images.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) site and download `Photos Sample` .It describes in detail How to crop. Hope this helps.