# xna wp7- photoChooser crop

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

hey when i use the pixelHeight/Width property ing photoChooser
a. only the height is adjusted
b. the photoChooserTask.Completed event doesn't work.
does anyone have some experience with it and know the answers?
thanks

Comment: If you want to see some more advanced image handling code on Windows Phone check out the source for this project: http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/

Comment: You might want to view this related question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391152/windows-phone-7-wp7-photochoosertask-with-crop

Answer (score 1):

In the emulator, the `PhotoChooserTask` crop is known to fail in the older version of the SDK (pre-NoDo) and the `Completed` event will never be triggered. On the phone, however, it works correctly.

Showing your code will also help, since you might be missing something obvious.

Comment: hi. when i delete the pixel, the completed is triggered so the code is fine. is it possible to get it right somehow on the emulator?

Comment: and what about the width crop

Comment: 1) What release of the tools are you using? 2) Show the snippet where you are invoking the PhotoChooserTask

Comment: photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
            photoChooserTask.PixelHeight = 10;
            photoChooserTask.PixelWidth = 90;
            photoChooserTask.ShowCamera = true;
            photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);

Comment: when i dont use the pixelHeight and pixelWidth properties the event is triggered but when i do use it , it doesn't. how can i trigger it with those properties?

Comment: First of all, you are not invoking `photoChooserTask.Show();` - `ShowCamera` only sets the setting to show the possibility to take a picture instead of selecting one from the library. Second, the cropping is done in a proportionate manner. So the height/width you are specifying is going to be taken relatively to the image, not how it would look like in the viewfinder. At the end, you get the correct size anyway.