# Crop option in CameraChooser Task like PhotoChooserTask

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, image-processing, windows-phone-8, crop

In Windows Phone, like [PhotoChooserTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391152/windows-phone-7-wp7-photochoosertask-with-crop), is there a simple way by which I can make sure user crop the photo by x*y( so make proper selection of area).

Whatsapp does this, so I am assuming there might be already existing way using which I can provide same croping functionality as in photoChoosertask by setting PixelWidth & PixelHeight

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to accomplish this. You can set the [ShowCamera](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask.showcamera%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property to true to enable the user to pick an existing picture OR take a new one!

```
var task = new PhotoChooserTask { ShowCamera = true, PixelHeight = 1280, PixelWidth = 780 };
task.Completed += TaskOnCompleted;
task.Show();
```

If you do not want to allow the user to pick an existing picture (by using the CameraCaptureTask) you would need to create your own cropping window or use a third party SDK like [Avery](http://www.aviary.com/wp7) or [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/image-editor.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I know that but I want to give user two separate option, take a photo or choose from album. I have looked in Telerik control but it was not available for wp7 yet. I was thinking whether there is a simple way to do it like whatsapp team is doing it. Not sure whether they are using any third party tool or not.

Anyhow, thanks for the reply :)